# Android equivalent function of VC++ sleep function

Tags: java, android

Is any equivalent function in android(Java) of sleep(VC++) function.  If no please provide a  method to do it.

eg.
`Sleep(5000);` // a delay of 5000 milliseconds

thanks

Comment: See my comment to that answer - don't use `sleep(...)` in Android code unless you know what it is doing. The chances are it could cause an ANR.

Comment: I know the question was asked and answered, but I have a question for you. *Why* do you want to sleep, or think you need to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [Thread.sleep()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29) method.

```
try {
        //thread to sleep for the specified number of milliseconds
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: @KazekageGaara : Please don't advise people to use `Thread.sleep(...)` for Android code. Using `sleep(...)` is a hack in any coding and in Android it can cause an ANR popup (Application Not Responding). This is a really bad way of doing things.

Comment: @Squonk It most frequently doesn't give such problems. Millions of splash-screens are running on Android devices thanks to `Thread.sleep()`. And thousands of tutorials advice to do the same.

Comment: @KazekageGaara : Splash screens have no place in Android apps and there are plenty of good reasons why they shouldn't. Splash screens are just another hack where the developers feel they should do something because 'it looks pretty'. There aren't any tutorials from reputable Android developers that would advise anyone to add a splash screen to their app - it basically breaks the UX.

Comment: @KazekageGaara Just because a tutorial advises to do something doesn't mean it is right. It just means some other person read it somewhere and thought they'd show their "infinite wisdom" to the world.

Comment: @Squonk well. Thanks for the information. And sorry for my attitude. :-) My knowledge in Android is limited to the tutorials and my experimental projects.